# How should I generate cache keys

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I want to cache following models and a shortened link for each Question.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField('text', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publication date', default=timezone.now)
    allow_multiple_choices = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField('text', max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField('votes', default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

How should I generate keys? Is something like this sufficient?

```
cache.set('question' + question.id, question)
cache.set('shortened' + question.id, shortened)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do. But am not sure about the scope of the instances created. If they are global, we have guaranteed non-overlapping of keys.

From the documentation of [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id)

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long
>   integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object
>   during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may
>   have the same id() value.

May be you should try other approaches, which guarantees keys uniqueness for your collection and also have a uniform distribution.
In our implementation, we will generate some hashcode (**md5 or sha1**) from  instance identification data.